# Oracle Attunity Connector for SSIS returning ORA-01843 not a valid month

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oracle11g, odp.net

I'm trying to access at one of the corporate database of my company using the Attunity Connector. The database is probably based and build in United State with their currency format of currency and datetime. The database is probably on Oracle 10 or 11G.

I have a Windows Server 2008 64bit with Microsoft SQL Server 2012 BI Edition. I have also Oracle Instant Client 11G 32 and 64bit installed. The Windows Server 2008 is Canadian French however I have modified the currency and the datetime information in Windows to be in American format. I have also modified the NLS_Lang to be in AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8. I also have installed the Attunity Oracle Connector 2.0 for .NET.

I am trying to gather the data using SSIS to push them to my SQL Server Database.

I have verified if my connection to the database is successful using the Oracle SQL Developper. I had the exact same error ORA-01843 before in SQL Developper before I added in the sqldevelopper.conf the line : AddVMOption -Duser.language=en

The problem is when I'm tying to make my connection with SSIS using any .NET oracle Connector to a view who contain date, I always have the same error, the same I used to have before I've modified SQL Developper to be in english saying that it's not a valid month.

I don't know if anyone had face this error and knows a work around or if anyone knows to modified the .NET Dateformat.

Thanks for help !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed :**

I did :

1. Change my regional setting to be exactly the same as my remote server
2. Re-install Oracle Instant Client 11G in 32bit and 64bit

And now it's working.

Moral :

Oracle + Microsoft in different language and regional setting is a source of problem.

Answer (score 0):

1) It would help a lot to see the error

2) There are a lot of "probably" on your question. If you don't know if you are connecting to a Oracle 10 or 11G, how can you know the right driver?

3) Despite that, try to configure a linked server using your Oracle driver to see if it at least work

Comment: I just updated the error message. The thing is, I actually can access to the Oracle Database and read data using SQL Developer. I can also read data with SSIS to any table who doe not have any date field. 

The problem is that I can't read any table who have a date field in Oracle. It's like if SSIS (.NET) and Oracle doesn't seem to share the same date format and I don't know how to make the Oracle Connector to read anyway any table who have a date format. 

So my question is more if there is a way to force change the "NLS_Lang" of the Oracle .NET Driver to read the database.